# Is it possible to have two sets of categories in Outlook?

Tags: c#, outlook, vsto, outlook-addin, office-addins

Is it possible to have two sets of categories in Outlook?
Like one set of categories are languages which will include 5 languages and
second set would be product type. I need to assign language category and product type category to each email.

If it is not possible to have two sets of category, I would like to put all categories to one set but would only like call them separately in combo box.

Like.

```
Outlook.Application application = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application();
Outlook.Folder folder = application.ActiveExplorer().CurrentFolder as Outlook.Folder;
Outlook.Store store = folder.Store;
Outlook.Categories categories = store.Categories;
foreach (Outlook.Category category in categories)
{
    if (category != null)
    {
        ComboBox1.Items.Add(category.Name);
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("There are no categories.");
    }
}
```

Is it possible to populate above combo box with only language categories? May be by adding where condition.

I know there is way to do it with user defined properties but wondering if I can achieve this using categories.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I follow Victor's suggestion and added same prefix to each category sets. Here is what worked for me, if someone looking for exact answer.

```
foreach (var category in categories
                    .Cast<Outlook.Category>()
                    .Where(c => c.Name.Contains("l_")))
{
     // do something here
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Name the categories of the first set (language related) as l_English, l_German etc and the categories of the second set (type related) as t_construction etc.

Comment: How can I pull only language related categories and avoid type related categories in this case?